# Phenomenology of photon pair production in non linear crystals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics

Could anyone describe the mechanism that produces photon pairs when a beam of light incides on a non linear crystal?

I'm aware of the conservation arguments than can be made with the two produced beams in relation to the original beam, but the actual mechanism by which a photon "turns" into a pair of photons eludes me.

Comment: Quantum mechanism is a phenomenological science. It does not explain the mechanism. It only describes the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a lot of questions about splitting photons, but contrary to popular belief you cannot split a photon into two photons.

What really happens inside the crystal is that the original incident photon gets absorbed:

1. either by a single atom/electron system inside the crystal
2. or by the molecules/the crystal lattice

Thus, the incident photons ceases to exist as a photon and gets converted into the energy of the atom/electron system or molecules of the crystal lattice.

Consequently, something called (cascade) two photon emission happens. These photons' emission can happen from:

1. either a single atom/electron system

in this case the single atom/electron system emits the originally absorbed total energy in two steps, cascades.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04349.pdf

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022231310003017

2. from different locations inside the crystal lattice

> However, a new nonlocalized mechanism for the production of correlated photon pairs in SPDC has highlighted that occasionally the individual photons that constitute the pair can be emitted from spatially separated points.[17][18]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion

> In principle,
>   this effect enables a pair of correlated photons to emerge
>   from two spatially separated origin points, and this introduces new positional uncertainty of a fundamental quantum
>   origin. In the following analysis, using a quantum electrodynamical (QED) formalism, we fully account for both
>   localized and nonlocalized emission.

https://ueaeprints.uea.ac.uk/id/eprint/63173/1/PhysRevLett.118.133602.pdf